# What's wrong with using NSObject's hash to create an NSMutableDictionary key?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In a few places I've needed object-to-object mappings, and have used NSMutableDictionary as a lookup table. The key has been a boxed NSObject hash, eg:

```
  [dict setObject:newObject forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[keyObject hash]]];
```

where keyObject is an instance of a custom class, which inherits NSObject's - (NSUInteger)hash implementation as-is. I have retained references to keyObject elsewhere, which I can use to get hold of newObject thusly:

```
[dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[keyObject hash]]]
```

This has seemed to work so far, though the app concerned is yet young.

Matt Gallagher, however, writes about this approach:

> [(don't laugh, I've seen it done)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/nsmaptable-more-than-nsdictionary-for.html)

which slightly undermines my confidence (and as this is for an iOS app I can't use his suggested NSMapTable).

Can anyone point out what's wrong with using NSObject's hash in this way, and what might be a better approach for a simple object-object mapping for an iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the non-uniqueness of hashes, if you shoehorn them into an `unsigned int` as you have done here, you’ve actually guaranteed that even a `-hash` method that returns the object pointer directly will not necessarily result in a unique key.

If you are going to do this, then rather than using `NSNumber`, at least use `NSValue` with the `+valueWithPointer:` and `-pointerValue` methods.

If you really want an `NSDictionary` interface and can’t use `NSMapTable` for some reason, you could use Core Foundation instead to create a dictionary that has raw object pointers as its keys.  If you do that, you can even choose how the memory management works for objects you’re using as keys in the dictionary; for instance, you may want to retain the keys, you may want to copy the keys, or you may decide that all you care about is the pointer value itself.

Comment: "Shoehorn"? On iOS, `sizeof(NSUInteger) == sizeof(unsigned int)`.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: `On iOS, sizeof(NSUInteger) == sizeof(unsigned int)` While that may currently be true, doesn't `NSValue` with `valueWithPointer:` state intent more clearly?

Comment: @drewk: I think using the address is the right way to go, and `+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]` is a great way to do that. I was just trying to point out that alastair's answer seems to be incorrectly referring to OS X.

Comment: @alistair: NSObject's hash returns an NSUInteger (no shoehorn req'd). I was going this route because on iOS I don't have NSMapTable available. The CF route might be tempting at some point, though I'm not familiar enough with CF right now.

Comment: @drewk, @josh: NSValue with the pointer value looks like a good way to go.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I hadn’t spotted that this was iOS, but I still stand by my remark; you shouldn’t make assumptions that any integer type (other than `uintptr_t`) can hold a pointer.

Comment: I understand: I miss the iOS tag all the time, and get halfway through writing "Well, NSView only foo's when you blah blah blah..." before I realize. :) But as for the type of the variable into which you put the return of `hash`, well, you shouldn't assume that it _is_ an address. Doing `uintptr_t theHash = [myObj hash];` is just as bad as assuming that a pointer is a certain size; the method returns `NSUInteger`, so you should use that.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Entirely agree.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: NSObject's default implementation just returns its memory location, I think. Which ought to be enough to specify instance equality during the lifetime of the instance.

Comment: What if you use the object's memory location directly? Then it wouldn't matter if someone else implements a different `hash` method.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But either way it's exactly what MG is laughing at in the post I linked to. He clearly sees something wrong (or at least amusing) with using a boxed memory address as a key in this way, and I'm wondering why. Also what would be a better approach to feigning an associative array in obj c.

Comment: Maybe what he finds awkward is the boxing? There may be a better approach, but I don't see anything wrong with using the memory address. (I'd still avoid `hash` since we have no control over overridden behavior.)

Comment: @Cris: I agree with Jon's comment. Reading the blog post, I don't think Matt was saying that it shouldn't be done, just that it's kind of an awkward workaround to a problem that is now solved by the availability of `NSMapTable`. Use the address directly, rather than relying on `hash` to not have been overridden; the address of an object _has to_ be unique, so it should work splendidly as a key. Interesting question, BTW.

Comment: @Jon @Josh -- you're both right re what Matt had meant; he's pointed out that it's the awkwardness of un/boxing VS using a data structure with the necessary facility (ie. NSMapTable) that he was referring to, rather than any real unfeasibility.